# How to correct the exception database.ocf' is locked by another process in orientdb?

Tags: java, orientdb

I'm getting the exception when I try to connect to the orient db using Java. Below is the exception I'm getting.

```
Jun 07, 2016 12:43:40 PM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFO: OrientDB auto-config DISKCACHE=891MB (heap=891MB direct=891MB os=4,006MB), assuming maximum direct memory size equals to maximum JVM heap size
Jun 07, 2016 12:43:40 PM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
WARNING: MaxDirectMemorySize JVM option is not set or has invalid value, that may cause out of memory errors. Please set the -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=4006m option when you start the JVM.
Jun 07, 2016 12:43:40 PM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
WARNING: MaxDirectMemorySize JVM option is not set or has invalid value, that may cause out of memory errors. Please set the -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=4006m option when you start the JVM.
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OFileLockedByAnotherProcessException: File 'F:\Program Files\orientdb-community-2.2.0\databases\mydbo\database.ocf' is locked by another process, maybe the database is in use by another process. Use the remote mode with a OrientDB server to allow multiple access to the same database at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.fs.OFileClassic.lock(OFileClassic.java:756)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.fs.OFileClassic.openChannel(OFileClassic.java:813)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.fs.OFileClassic.open(OFileClassic.java:603)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OSingleFileSegment.open(OSingleFileSegment.java:51)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OStorageConfigurationSegment.load(OStorageConfigurationSegment.java:80)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.open(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:186)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.open(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:231)
    at orient.insert.Insert.main(Insert.java:12)
```

this is the code that i tried.

```
ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("plocal:F:/Program Files/orientdb-community-2.2.0/databases/mydbo").open("admin", "admin");

ODocument doc = new ODocument("Person");
doc.field( "name", "Luke" );
doc.field( "surname", "Skywalker" );
doc.field( "city", new ODocument("City").field("name","Rome").field("country", "Italy") );


doc.save();
db.close();
```

I can't figure out the error I'm having.

Answer (score 3):

You have a server running and you try to open the database from another process in plocal.
Could you please verify that you have no active OrientDB instances while accessing it in plocal (console or external processes) and that you open one plocal connection at a time?

Comment: I have also been facing the same issue while running a distributed server